# Adding parameters to jQuery ajax calls, best to add to URL or object?

Tags: javascript, jquery

When passing parameters to the server using jQuery get, post, or ajax, is it better/more proper to attach them to the URL or add them to an object?  If the answer is based on the particular situation, what circumstances makes one approach better than the other? For instance, see the following.

```
$.get('serverScript.php?v1=123&v2=321', { v3: '111' }, function(data) {
    ...
});

$.get('serverScript.php', { v1:123, v2:321, v3: '111' }, function(data) {
    ...
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever you can use an object to represent your data rather than perform string manipulation - do it.

- The first approach uses manual string manipulation to serialize data.
- The second approach uses an automatic, tested, spec complaint parser to serialize the same data.

String manipulation for serializing data yourself should be used as a last resort. It's harder to test, it's less clear and more susceptible to mistakes.

This is exactly like the fact you'd use `JSON.stringify` rather than build JSON yourself.

Comment: For my particular application, `{v3:'111'}` is a property (actually a call back function) which can be overridden by the user.  Do you still recommend doing it the way you show?  If so, I can easily do so but will need to merge the two objects using jQuery `extend` or some JavaScript code.  Thanks

Comment: @user1032531 I don't understand your _specific_ issue or why you'd need `jQuery.extend` (what are v1,v2 and v3 anyway? Why not have meaningful names :)). However yes, I still recommend it 100%.

Comment: `v1` and `v2` are parameters which should always be passed to the server, and are set to things like the server component, controller, etc.  `v3` and maybe even `v4`, etc, are parameters which will be changed based on how the plugin is configured, and are set to the page record ID, etc.

Comment: Yes, 100%. The first approach.

Comment: Thanks Ben.  And by stating "the first approach", you mean my second example, right?

Comment: @user1032531 yes, I meant the second approach - sorry :)